# How do I create Json requests in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json

I have a great [framework](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/api/index.html) however I cannot figure out how to create requests.  All the tutorials assume you are simply downloading and parsing Json data - but I need to build a Json request send it off and then parse the response.

Anyone have ideas and in particular sample code which builds up the request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The framework doesn't handle NSObject but NSDictionary seems to work:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"value1", @"key1", @"value2", @"key2", nil];

NSString *requestJson = [jsonDictionary JSONRepresentation];
NSLog(@"requestJson %@", requestJson);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this JSON framework...you can use the JSONRepresentation method on NSDictionary and NSArray.....

Comment: That doesn't seem to work:  -JSONRepresentation failed. Error trace is: (
    Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=4 UserInfo=0x680abe0 "Not valid type for JSON"

Answer (score 0):

You should download JSON lib, then import header:

```
#import "NSObject+SBJSON.h"
```